# c# detect when there are too many objects

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a c# app in which the user does some business stuff by working with a wpf treeview, using drag&drop. The Undo stack offers some user functionality to roll back everything from the start, and is about limited for about ~500 steps.

So if those objects references are inside the undostack, the GC is NOT allowed to finalize them, because the user may want it back.

Now using copy and paste, a software tester can go this way and copy 2 nodes inside each other,repeating this for e.g. 20 times, which means the objects count grows by cloning from 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, to finally 1048576. So that a copy operation may lead to create e.g. 1048576 more objects, and so the Undo stack would store 1048576 object references, for ONE Undo step.
The tester can easily create this app crash:

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

So limiting the Undo stack does not solve the problem of too many objects.

Besides that there's no use-case having so much objects, I `d like to be simply on the safe side.

The msdn tells me:

> Be sure you have enough memory for internal purposes and new managed
>   objects.

How can I achieve this in my case, maintaining the Undo-feature?

Comment: ok, but This would be a work-around, when the object count already has grown too high. 2ndly, depending on the current NET memory management in the framework, there are varying places where the exception occurs. And it would be a large job to put each "create" of any object in any class inside try - catch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to serialize your object and save it on disk so that they can be loaded back when undo is required.

Here the key concept is serialization. Your object should be serializable to do this. when required, you can deserialize these objects and load in to memory.

Comment: "Here the key concept is serialization" - I heard of that, thanks

Comment: The data can grow by the power of 2 then this will just push undo limit a bit higher, certainly not to 500. Maybe OP could implement some kind of ref count - if an object is the same in two undo steps just increase the ref count instead of holding object in memory.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recomend you to avoid playing with GC. I'd consider change your business logic(may be limit copy?). Also, may be you can store (persist) your undo steps somewhere on the disk, abd allow them to be gone  from memory.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of options, you could look into using [MemoryFailPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint.aspx) to make it easier to catch the exception. OutOfMemory exceptions are trickier to handle than other expcetions and you can use the `MemoryFailPoint` class reduces the chance of getting an OOM exception.

Having said that, it would be much more preferable to serialize your undo stack, or alter your business logic to avoid being able to copy/paste without limits, as mentioned in the other answers.